# How to define global text color for button in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to define global text color for button in App.xaml? The background setting fine.

Background settings xaml markup:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Style>
 </Application.Resources>
```

And the text color?

Sorry for my bad English. Please help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `Foreground` property to apply text color formatting, similarly to how you use the `Background` property:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
```